# Detect headset button press in swift 5 Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift5

I want a single view application which detect button click of iPhone headphone for below situations:

1. original iPhone headset
2. AirPods Pro via Bluetooth

I tested several code in stack overflow but they didn’t help me. may I should active permission as well